# ExecutorService with multiple threads not working normally but works fine in debug mode

Tags: java, multithreading

Basically I have to process a large csv file with almost 1 million records using multi threading.

I created a class IngestionCallerThread

```
public class IngestionCallerThread {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        int count = 0;
        InputStream ios = IngestionCallerThread.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("aa10.csv");

        byte[] buff = new byte[8000];

        int bytesRead = 0;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        while ((bytesRead = ios.read(buff)) != -1) {
            bao.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        byte[] data = bao.toByteArray();

        ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        BufferedReader fileInputStreamBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bin));

        while ((fileInputStreamBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;
        }
        bin.reset();

        int numberOfThreads = 12;
        int rowsForEachThread = count / numberOfThreads;
        int remRows = count % numberOfThreads;
        int startPosition = 0;
        System.out.println(count);
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads && startPosition < count; i++) {
            if (remRows > 0 && i + 1 >= numberOfThreads)
                rowsForEachThread = remRows;

            IngestionThread ingThread = new IngestionThread(bin, startPosition, rowsForEachThread);
            es.execute(ingThread);
            startPosition = (startPosition + rowsForEachThread);
        }
        es.shutdown();
        if (es.isTerminated()) {
            System.out.println("Completed");
        }
        // t2.start();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

which I use to call another Runnable class that I have implemented

```
public class IngestionThread implements Runnable {

InputStream is;
long startPosition;
long length;

public IngestionThread(InputStream targetStream, long position, long length) {
    this.is = targetStream;
    this.startPosition = position;
    this.length = length;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int currentPosition = 0;
    try {
        is.reset();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader fileInputStreamBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    if (startPosition != 0) {   
        String line;
        try {
            while (((line = fileInputStreamBufferedReader.readLine())) != null) {
                if (currentPosition + 1 == startPosition)
                    break;
                currentPosition++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        int execLength = 0;
        String line;
        while ((line = fileInputStreamBufferedReader.readLine()) != null && execLength < length) {
            System.out.println(line);
            execLength++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I tested with a small csv file of 20 records. The issue is when I debug the class almost all the records are getting printed. But when I run the class sometimes 15 records are read, sometimes 12 records are read. I am not sure what is the issue. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of your problems is that you have a number of threads reading from the different `BufferedReader` objects that wrap a shared `ByteArrayInputStream`.  There is no synchronization, and that means that different threads will reading sections of the stream that other threads are supposed to be reading.

Each of the threads needs its own `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: Fixed the issue and it worked like a charm.. Thanks a lot.. :)